# Calathea tubers: Any point in attempting to propagate them?

Tags: roots, propagation, cuttings

As I repotted my Calatheas, I noticed that some have potato-like structures attached to the roots. Few have detached while repotting so I tried to plant them and see if something sprouts. That was at least two weeks ago. Nothing sprouted yet, but the structures are still firm and did not rot. Should I give it more time, or is it futile?